# How to delete a group in Skype?

Tags: skype

I created a group with 2 people in it in Skype. I want to delete the group.

Where is the option for that?

Answer (score 6):

Right click the group you wish to delete and select *Remove From Your Contacts*.

[image]

Note: this doesn't delete the contacts inside the group, only the group itself.

Comment: He's talking about the group itself, not the contact. You can use the same screenshot, but it's leave conversation, then hide it.

Comment: Yeah I figured :) My note at the bottom is just to say it won't go and do anything like delete the contacts in the group (because that could potentially be an unwanted side effect); it will just delete the group. Remove From Your Contacts is the correct option to use for a group, even if the name is misleading.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! Now I can remove all these spam groups I'm in..:p

Comment: This answer has become pretty useless without context.  From the widget style, it looks like this is for "Skype for Windows Desktop"?  Any idea whether the same option exists on other Skype clients?

Answer (score 4):

If you are admin (creator) of that group, you can remove all members from that group and then leave the group. It will delete the group truly. That means no skype user could not be able to use (e.g. see history, send/receive message) that group anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Option presents on skype panel. Select the group you wish to delete. right click and select delete option.

And you're done.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no option to delete an entire group, except to click Leave Group, and then Hide or Block the group account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creator of the group then, remove all the members in the group and at last leave the group. Group will get deleted automatically.